# SQL Server: Insert record if not found in table from a function in Select

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions, sql-server-2014, openrowset

I am using `OPENROWSET` for importing a `.csv` file into SQL Server 2014.

This is my query

```
SELECT 
    ufnGetChargeTypeId([Charge Type]) AS ChargeTypeId, [Description] 
FROM 
    OPENROWSET ('MSDASQL', 
                'Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}; DBQ=D:\Files\;', 
                'SELECT * from [myfile.csv]' )
```

`[Charge Type]` is column header in the `.csv` file. `ufnGetChargeTypeId` is a function which returns `ChargeTypeId` if found in table `ChargeType` which is a reference table.

Working fine if `[Charge Type]` exist. I want to insert `[Charge Type]` in table if not found and return `ChargeTypeId`. User defined functions don't support INSERT/UPDATE in table.

One solution is to use a stored procedure but I am calling function in `Select` statement and you can't exec stored procedure in `Select` statement.

Would you suggest any solution to my problem.

Comment: Dump to one staging table and then do comparisons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first insert all missing types, then run your query:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE([Charge Type] varchar(4000), [Description] text)

INSERT INTO @T
SELECT [Charge Type], [Description]
FROM 
    OPENROWSET ('MSDASQL', 
                'Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}; DBQ=D:\Files\;', 
                'SELECT * from [myfile.csv]' )

INSERT INTO ChargeTypes ([Charge Type])
SELECT DISTINCT [Charge Type]
FROM @T
WHERE [Charge Type] NOT IN (SELECT [Charge Type] FROM ChargeTypes)

SELECT 
    ufnGetChargeTypeId([Charge Type]) AS ChargeTypeId, [Description] 
FROM @T
```